# Question About Dynamically Allocated Objects

Tags: c++, object, pointers, syntax

I'm a beginner and having a hard time understanding how I would dynamically allocate an object and then pass the memory address of another dynamically allocated object, to a member of the first one.

Given a struct containing an integer and a pointer to another struct of the same type like this:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next_ptr; 
};
```

Would:

```
Node *node1 = new Node(); 
Node *node2 = new Node();
```

Allocate memory for an object of the type `Node` or only create a pointer to the object `node1`?

Could `node1->next_ptr = node2` be the solution?

Comment: Yes that looks correct. Why did you think there was a problem?

Comment: `new` always (if possible) creates an object on the heap and returns a pointer to that object, through which you can use it. Pointer itself is usually created on stack (i.e. without `new`). `node1->next_ptr = node2` will do the thing you expect - pointer within `node1` will be now pointing to the same object as `node2` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the community!

Your code is ok. Operator **new** will create an object in memory and it will return pointer on that object.

And `node1->next_ptr = node2` will "connect" node1 and node2. Or node1.next_ptr will be pointer on object like node2. 
You should check linked list tutorials. Feel free to ask...